# Fixed point of an exponential function

Tags: numerical-methods, linear-transformations, fixed-points

$$f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$$ s.t $$f(x)=e^x$$
How many fixed point of f(x) exists?

Comment: Hint: $f(0) = f'(0) = 1$ and $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x$

Comment: A fixed point of $f(x)$ is a solution to $e^x=x$. You can show that there are no solutions by showing that $e^x-x>0$. Obviously no solution can exist for $x<0$ and for $x\geq 0$ you can expand $e^x$ as a Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

$$\because \ e^x =x \ \ \ \Rightarrow \frac{1}{e^x}=\frac{1}{x}\\
\\
\\
\therefore x\ e^{-x}=1\ \ \ \Rightarrow -x\ e^{-x}=-1\\
\\
\therefore \ \ z\ e^z \ =-1 \ \ \ \ \therefore \ z=W(-1)\\ where \ W is\ lambert\ function
\\
\\$$

and this exist in C not R

**so no fixed points for this function\ in this domain**